# Are there tools to dissect a pdf or tiff by coordinates?

Tags: android, pdf, image-processing, tiff

I am attempting to programmatically "chop up" a pdf or tiff image into several smaller regions for use on mobile devices (android).  The layout of the original document will always be the same, so using predefined coordinates of rectangles would be ideal.

Is there any software that does this already? If not, what tools are there to accomplish this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to doing this on your development machine, as part of a build process. If so, try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

One method of "chopping up" a PDF would be to duplicate the page N times, and set a "crop box" on each page to only show the portion you wanted.

This can be done quite efficiently in terms of file size... just a little overhead for the page definition.  All the page content, resources, and so forth can be shared.

The details of this are specific to your environment.  As we don't know your environment, and my crystal ball is on the fritz again, I can't be of much more help.